# How to convert slice to array?

Tags: arrays, go, slice, reflect

I want to implement a method to convert a `interface{}` slice to a `interface{}` array which has equal length to the given slice. It's similar to below:

```golang
func SliceToArray(in []interface{}) (out interface{}) {
 ...
}
// out's type is [...]interface{} and len(out)==len(in)
```

How can I implement this method?

EDIT:
Any possible to use `reflect.ArrayOf` to implement this?

Comment: This is a very unusual, and probably pointless, implementation - can you describe what you're actually trying to accomplish? There's probably a better way, most likely just using slices normally.

Comment: actually,I want to use a indeterminate slice as the key of map, becase of not capamrable(https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) of slice,I want to use an array which holds all elements in the slice as the key with size as small as possible

Comment: If you need your map keys to be arrays of inconsistent length, you probably want to reconsider the design that led you to that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [reflect.ArrayOf](https://godoc.org/reflect#ArrayOf) to create the array type given the slice element type.  Use [reflect.New](https://godoc.org/reflect#New) to create a value of that type. Use [reflect.Copy](https://godoc.org/reflect#Copy) to copy from the slice to the array.

```
func SliceToArray(in interface{}) interface{} {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(in)
    if s.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("not a slice")
    }
    t := reflect.ArrayOf(s.Len(), s.Type().Elem())
    a := reflect.New(t).Elem()
    reflect.Copy(a, s)
    return a.Interface()
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pHujV-0qMiQ)

This function is useful for creating a map key from a slice and other scenarios where a comparable value is required.  Otherwise, it's usually best to use a slice when the length can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Go 1.20 (Q1 2023) should facilitate such a conversion, after [issue 46505: "spec: allow conversion from slice to array"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46505)

This is addressed with [CL 430415](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/430415/), [428938 (`type`)](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/428938/), [430475 (`reflect`)](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/430475/) and [429315 (`spec`)](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/429315/)

> ### Conversions from slice to array or array pointer
>
> Converting a slice to an array yields an array containing the elements of the underlying array of the slice.
>
> Similarly, converting a slice to an array pointer yields a pointer to the underlying array of the slice.
>
> In both cases, if the [length](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity) of the slice is less than the length of the array, a [run-time](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Run_time_panics) panic occurs.

```golang
s := make([]byte, 2, 4)

a0 := ([0]byte)(s)
a1 := ([1]byte)(s[1:])   // a1[0] == s[1]
a2 := ([2]byte)(s)       // a2[0] == s[0]
a4 := ([4]byte)(s)       // panics: len([4]byte) > len(s)
```